# Why is the icon of the Google 3D Tiles not orange after importing a 0.1x0.1km 3D "city-rectangle"?

Tags: 3d-view

first of all, I am using blender for 1 hour in total, I'm totally a newby.

I want to use google 3D tiles; I already selected an 0.1x0.1km rectangle and pasted it in blender (this step I did right) however, when I press "import" a file named "Google 3D Tiles" is created but I cannot located it in my 3d map. How can I get to it?

Compared to the youtuber ( https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JC9IYCF-IAE&pp=ygUeYmxlbmRlciBnb29nbGUgbWFwcyAzZCBjZyBnZWVr )I watched, I cannot "open" the file "Google 3D tiles" (picture) or in other words, there's no orange icon. When I press "." nothing happens at all?!

Any help is very welcomed, thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Please add a link to the YT tutorial you are following by [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/311962/edit) your question and inserting the link into it. At the moment we have no idea what you are talking about. The image you've included just shows an empty Collection called 'Google 3D Tiles' which doesn't really help!

Comment: I also do not understand, you selected a rectangle and pasted it in Blender? Where did you paste it? What assures you this step was correct? When you already pasted it in Blender, what exactly did you have to import? As @JohnEason said, the white icon (without a hierarchy arrow to the left to expand it) means there is an empty collection of that name. If you got this into your current file, then you did neither open nor import it but used the _Append_ function. And since appending a collection has no option "append only collection without objects" this means, the collection was already empty.

Comment: Thank you very much I now added the youtube video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simpler method is to use this blender addon called osm https://prochitecture.gumroad.com/l/blender-osm
but use the openstreetmap instead of google 3d tiles
only downside is you have to input your own materials
https://youtu.be/IX2gOPm5YIA?si=jC9pv78SBl16QrKy

Comment: Thanks! but what was my mistake?

Comment: you probably appended a collection with no objects